# Force by dielectric

Tags: electrostatics, experimental-physics, dielectric

Consider the following thought experiment: Suppose we have a setup with a dielectric medium of dielectric constant $\kappa$ on a horizontal floor extending from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. And we have a charge at height $h$ above the floor; we neglect gravity. What is the  force on the charge due to the dielectric? How much force do we need to apply in order to maintain the charge at rest?